# MySQL view syntax, where clause greater than or equal to first monday of last april

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm writing the syntax for a view to locate data in a database where a timestamp col is greater than or equal to the date of the first monday of last april. I can't use a static date as the first monday of last april is relevant to the current date.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Ive spent quite a but of time trying to fathom out how I would do this with MySQL's datetime functions, and not had any luck thus far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get last april for current date:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ((4-MONTH(CURDATE()))%24-12)%12 MONTH);
```

get year of last april for current date:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ((4-MONTH(CURDATE()))%24-12)%12 MONTH));
```

get first monday of april 2013, for instance:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2013-04-07',INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2013-04-07') DAY);
```

get first monday of last april:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ((4-MONTH(CURDATE()))%24-12)%12 MONTH)),"-04-07"),INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ((4-MONTH(CURDATE()))%24-12)%12 MONTH)),"-04-07")) DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE year(adddate(created_at, interval 9 month)) >= year(curdate());
```

This is just shifting everything by 9 months into the future, so April 1st, 2013 will appear to be January 1st, 2014 for the purposes of the where clause.

You could also shift everything back by 3 months, but then you would also have to shift the curdate to make sure that it worked between January 1st and April 1st of next year

[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64d49/4)